# How to insert variable into post method header?

Tags: angular, api, http-headers

I am trying to insert a variable, which is assigned a value from user input, into the header of a post method. I can not seem to get it to work. Any help would be great.

I want to insert the variable called "value" where it says "apple".

Here is the relevant component.ts code :

```
  value : string = '';
  update(value: string) { this.value = value; }
 

  getResults(){
  
    this.http.post('http://whereIammakingpostto-2/services/issuerRestService/findIssuersBySearchCriteria', {name : "apple"}).subscribe(data => {
    this.searchResult = data; 
    console.log(data)
})

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

write your code as below.

```
value : string = '';
  update(value: string) { this.value = value; }
   getResults(){
  let request:any = {};
request.name = "apple";
request.value = this.value;
    this.http.post('http://whereIammakingpostto-2/services/issuerRestService/findIssuersBySearchCriteria', request).subscribe(data => {
    this.searchResult = data; 
    console.log(data)
})
}
```

Comment: So where do I insert my value variable ? "apple" is just a placeholder for where my value variable is supposed to be.